# How to make the following quicksort more 'pythonic'

Tags: python, python-3.x, quicksort

I just implemented [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) in python-3 and the following is a excerpt for the swapping mechanism involved in each sub array.

Now, I can't help but notice that it looks an awful lot like a C-based loop. Which makes sense since I'm coming over from a long time of C++ development.
I was wondering if this loop can be made more *pythonic*.

I tried using `for items in array` but that's not helpful since the iterator should **not** increase for every round of the loop.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
#  last elem is pivot at start
pivPos = end
#  iterate the list and bring pivot to correct position
count = 0

while (count != pivPos):

    #  swap places with elem just before pivot
    if arr[count] >= arr[pivPos]:
        temp = arr[count]
        arr[count] = arr[pivPos - 1]
        arr[pivPos - 1] = temp

        #  now swap the pivot
        arr[pivPos - 1] = arr[pivPos]
        arr[pivPos] = temp

        #  update pivPos
        pivPos -= 1

    else:
        count += 1
        continue
```

Comment: The true pythonic way is called "timsort" :P

Comment: This looks perfectly fine. Atrocities have been made in the name of pythonicity. Don't try to over do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part:

```
temp = arr[count]
arr[count] = arr[pivPos - 1]
arr[pivPos - 1] = temp
arr[pivPos - 1] = arr[pivPos]
arr[pivPos] = temp
```

can be written without `temp` like this:

```
arr[count], arr[pivPos-1], arr[pivPos] = arr[pivPos-1], arr[pivPos], arr[count]
```

Also `continue` is redundant, you can remove it and the code will behave the same.

However the real pythonic way is:

```
arr.sort()
```

full edited code easy reference:

```
pivPos = end
count = 0
while count != pivPos:
    if arr[count] >= arr[pivPos]:
        arr[count], arr[pivPos-1], arr[pivPos] = arr[pivPos-1], arr[pivPos], arr[count]
        pivPos -= 1
    else:
        count += 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the type of loop to make it more readable? Classic while and for loops are a little discouraged in python it seems.

Comment: No, it seems pretty readable to me. You can drop the parens in the `while`.

Comment: @BaninAbrar the only two forms of loop in python are `for` and `while` - there is no other way to loop, you have to use those or call a function that uses them.

Comment: Right of course, I was just referring to "vanilla" **for** and **while** loops with no `forEach`business going on.

Comment: @BaninAbrar the only type of `for` python has is `forEach`. There is no "vanilla"  `for` in python. Since treesort algorithm doesn't traverse the sequence in a single direction, `foreach` (which is the normal `for` in python as I said, just to clarify) doesn't fit so we use `while`.